# SOLR: Is it it possible to index multiple timestamp:value pairs per document?

Tags: solr, date-range, multivalue

Is it possible in solr to index key-value pairs for a single document, like:

---

Document ID: 100

2011-05-01,20

2011-08-23,200

2011-08-30,1000

---

Document ID: 200

2011-04-23,10

2011-04-24,100

---

and then querying for documents with a specific value aggregation in a specific time range, i.e. "give me documents with sum(value) > 0 between 2011-08-01 and 2011-09-01" would return the document with id 100 in the example data above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a post from the [Solr User Mailing List](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Dealing-with-field-values-as-key-value-pairs-tt492462.html#a492465) where a couple of approaches for dealing with fields as key/value pairs are discussed.

> 1) encode the "id" and the "label" in the field value; facet on it; 
>   require clients to know how to decode.  This works really well for simple 
>   things where the the id=>label mappings don't ever change, and are 
>   easy to encode (ie "01234:Chris Hostetter").  This is a horrible approach 
>   when id=>label mappings do change with any frequency.
>
> 2) have a seperate type of "metadata" document, one per "thing" that you 
>   are faceting on containing fields for id and the label (and probably a 
>   doc_type field so you can tell it apart from your main docs) then once 
>   you've done your main query and gotten the results back facetied on id, 
>   you can query for those ids to get the corrisponding labels.  this works 
>   realy well if the labels ever change (just reindex the corrisponding 
>   metadata document) and has the added bonus that you can store additional 
>   metadata in each of those docs, and in many use cases for presenting an 
>   initial "browse" interface, you can sometimes get away with a cheap 
>   search for all metadata docs (or all metadata docs meeting a certain 
>   criteria) instead of an expensive facet query across all of your main 
>   documents.